# how to use matcaffe on windows

Tags: windows, matlab, caffe, matcaffe

I want to use Caffe with Matlab on windows 7. I downloaded Caffe on https://github.com/Microsoft/caffe/tree/master 
Then I built Caffe with visual studio 2013 (the whole solution'caffe' which includes libcaffe, matcaffe .. ). It built successfully.

But now how do I use it ?  In matlab I tried to configure (gpu/cpu) following these instructions: https://ahmedibrahimvt.wordpress.com/2016/04/18/caffe-in-matlab-matcaffe-simple-tutorial/

But matlab tells me it doesn't know Caffe :

> Undefined variable "caffe" or class "caffe.set_mode_gpu".
>
> Error in main (line 5) caffe.set_mode_gpu();

How to link/include caffe in matlab to be able to use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to have "caffe\matlab\" in your path 
try to use the Matlab addpath with the full path to your caffe\matlab folder

Comment: Have you succeeded training a net on Caffe from MATLAB?